# Transformation of a matrix, change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, coordinate-systems

Find the change of coordinate matrices:

Wherein B is the standard basis for P2
$$B' = (t^2+2,t+3,t^2+t+1) \\B" = (2t^2+t+1, t^2, 2t+1) \\ B= (t^2,t,1)
$$
$$P_{B'B}$$  means the transformation for the standard basis to B'

$$ B' = \{\,t^2 + 2\,,\; t+3\,,\; t^2+t+1\,\}$$

$$P_{BB'} \\ P_{B'B} \\P_{BB"}\\ P_{B"B} \\ P_{B'B"} \\ P_{B"B'}$$

The answers I got from  respectively(first four) were:
They are all wrong. 
What are the steps to do this kinds of questions?

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1  &0&2  \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \\2 &3&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0&0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\2 &0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 &0&0  \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\1 &0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 &1&1  \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 &0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What all those $\,B',B'',B'''\,$ mean? I thought $\,B'\,$ is the given basis and $\,B\,$ the standard one.

Comment: whoops i forgot to add them sorry.

Comment: "To add them"? To add who or what?

Comment: I have included the B' B" in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the vectors of $\mathcal{B}'$, represented as coordinate vectors in two ways. If $\mathcal{B}$ is the basis that we use for coordinates, then you have $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ but if $\mathcal{B}'$ is the basis that we use for coordinates, then you just have $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ When you ask for $P_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}'}$, you are therefore looking for a matrix that satisfies $$P_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}'}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\2&3&1\end{bmatrix}$$ so there you go; $P_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}'}$ is apparent.

The next one on your list is the inverse of $P_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}'}$.

The two after that can be found similarly.

For the last two, consider that $P_{\mathcal{B}''\mathcal{B}}P_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}'}=P_{\mathcal{B}''\mathcal{B}'}$.

Comment: Deleted my first answer after realizing I should have read more than the first column of the first matrix in your answers. Here's something more helpful.